# Expected number of heads from tossing 6 coins given that the heads are more than 2?

Tags: probability

I have approached this question in two ways and I am unsure why they give contradictory answers.

**First method.**

We have two heads already, just consider the remaining tosses as expectation of number of heads from four coin tosses, which is two. Therefore the overall expectation of number of heads from six coin tosses given that there are more than two heads is 4.

**Second method.**

Consider using conditional probability formula:

P(X Heads|greater than 2 heads) = P(X heads)/P(greater than 2 heads)

where the probability of X heads is the same as the probability of X heads and greater than 2 heads.

The probability of greater than two heads is the sum of P(X heads) from X=3 to 6, which is 42/(2^6) = 42/64 = P(H>2). The probability of X heads is just the number of outcomes with X heads divided by total number of outcomes, e.g there are 6!/(3!3!) outcomes for 3 heads giving a probability of 20/42. Thus the expected number of heads given that there are more than two heads is:

E( 6H | H>2) = sum( X*P(X heads) ) = 6 * 1/42 + 5 * 6/42 + 4*15/42 + 3*20/42 = 3.71

where the probability of getting zero, one or two heads isn't explicitly written as these terms equal zero.

Have I made a mistake in my reasoning for the second method? I am not very familiar with conditional expectations so perhaps I have missed something.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Congratulations on a good job explaining what you have done.  Your posts will look better, and be easier to read, if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format them.  Note that you have to enclose MathJax command in `$` signs for them to be effective.

Comment: The first method of reasoning is unjustified, because we won't necessarily have the first two coin tosses Heads, nor any other distinguished a priori tosses so determined.  The second approach can be justified in this case (basically use the definition of conditional probability).

Comment: The second method the right one, given the condition "at least 2 of the 6 flips are H". The first method would be right if you were given: a) the first two flips were H, or (b) the 2nd and 5th flips were H, or (c) two randomly chosen flips turned out to be H. The somewhat subtle point is that "at least 2 H" is not equivalent, as a given condition, to any of the conditions (a), (b), or (c) in this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me fix your work.

Let $X$ be the number of heads in 6 coins (it's confusing that you use also $H$ for the same thing).

Then (abusing notation: $P(X) = P(X=X)$ ):

$$P(X | X>2) = \frac{P(X  \cap X>2)}{P(X>2)} = \frac{P(X) \, I(X>2)}{P(X>2)} $$

where $$P(X)=\frac{1}{2^6}\binom{6}{X}$$ and $I()$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Then $$P(X>2) = \frac{1}{2^6}\left(\binom{6}{3} +\binom{6}{4}+\binom{5}{6}+\binom{6}{6}\right)=0.890625$$

And $$E[X | X>2]=\frac{3\binom{6}{3} +4\binom{6}{4}+5\binom{5}{6}+6\binom{6}{6}}{\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{4}+\binom{5}{6}+\binom{6}{6}}=\frac{156}{42}=3.7142857$$

This is essentially your second approach, which is the right one.

Your first method would be right if you were told that "the first two coins are head". But you are not told that, you are only told that at least two coins are head.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is correct.

The first method is wrong, because you're tacitly assuming that the first two tosses come up heads.  Suppose the first three tosses are $THH$.  You don't have four more tosses left to get heads.  What you've computed is the expected number of heads in $6$ tosses, given that the first two come up heads.